# swagger validadtion error for list in python

Tags: python, api, flask, swagger

I'm developing a python API with flask and swagger, and I want to change one of the inputs from string to list:

This is the current working code for the schema :

```
   /question:
    post:
      operationId: processor.convertInputString
      tags:
        - People
      summary: Create a person and add it to the people list
      description: Create a new person in the people list
      parameters:
        - name: input_string_2
          in: body
          description: Person to create
          required: True
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              question:
                type: list
                description: question to match

      responses:
        201:
          description: Successfully created person in list
```

and the request i'm using:

```
data =  {"question": "processor","num_results":3}
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
url = "http://localhost:5000/api/question"
data = requests.post(url,data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

This works fine, but I need To change {"question": "processor"} for:

```
{"question": ["processor"]}
```

but when I make that request I get this error:

```
'{\n  "detail": "[\'processor\'] is not of type \'string\'",\n  "status": 400,\n  "title": "Bad Request",\n  "type": "about:blank"\n}\n'
```

Hence I tried to change change the data type from string to list in the schema:

```
  schema:
    type: object
    properties:
      question:
        type: list
        description: question to match
```

But I get another error with that.

```
Failed validating 'oneOf' in schema['properties']['paths']['patternProperties']['^/']['properties']['post']['properties']['parameters']['items']:
    {'oneOf': [{'$ref': '#/definitions/parameter'},
               {'$ref': '#/definitions/jsonReference'}]}

On instance['paths']['/question']['post']['parameters'][0]:
    {'description': 'Person to create',
     'in': 'body',
     'name': 'input_string_2',
     'required': True,
     'schema': {'properties': {'question': {'description': 'question to '
                                                           'match',
                                            'type': 'list'}},
                'type': 'object'}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array/list of strings is defined as

```
question:
  type: array
  items:
    type: string
```

`type: list` is not a valid value for `type` in OpenAPI.